# Internet stops working after some time

Tags: wireless

After I log in to Ubuntu, internet works fine for some time (for around 45 mins or so) but then it suddenly stops working. I'm on 14.04 now and I've faced similar problem in 13.10.

I'm connected using Wifi, but I face the same issue when connected using ethernet cable.

Please ask me any details which can help in diagnosing the issue.

I get a dialog box which says "A system problem as occurred" and then internet crashes.

From `/var/log/syslog` -

```
cat /var/log/syslog | grep NetworkManager | grep error
Apr 10 01:50:55 <machine-name> NetworkManager[832]: <warn> error monitoring device for netlink events: No buffer space available
Apr 10 02:06:36 <machine-name> NetworkManager[760]: <error> [1397113596.497261] [nm-dns-dnsmasq.c:400] update(): dnsmasq owner not found on bus: Could not get owner of name 'org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.dnsmasq': no such name
```

From `dmesg | grep -e eth0 -e IPv -e dns -e DNS` -

```
dmesg | grep -e eth0 -e IPv -e dns -e DNS
[    0.920865] Key type dns_resolver registered
[    0.976650] r8169 0000:03:00.0 eth0: RTL8168evl/8111evl at 0xffffc90000c2a000, 18:67:b0:27:02:c6, XID 0c900800 IRQ 42
[    0.976652] r8169 0000:03:00.0 eth0: jumbo features [frames: 9200 bytes, tx checksumming: ko]
[   23.017231] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready
[   34.125468] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
[   34.125715] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
[   34.672505] r8169 0000:03:00.0 eth0: link down
[   34.672562] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready
[   34.672927] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready
[   41.473249] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlan0: link becomes ready
```

Comment: Do you see naything in /var/log/syslog?

Comment: @alci Please see this pastebin - http://pastebin.com/AYwq3wv9 I think the issue is `<info> (wlan0): IP6 addrconf timed out or failed.`

Comment: @alci Also check the updated content in the post from `/var/log/syslog`

Comment: @david6 can I grep for any keyword in dmesg that would help me in finding the issue?

Comment: Try: **`dmesg | grep -e eth0 -e IPv -e dns -e DNS`**

Comment: Do check your router log too. And check /var/log/syslog for "SYN".

Comment: @david6 updated question post with the output. Please check.

Comment: @Rinzwind I don't think there is any issue with the router because it works fine in Windows. Also, I don't see "SYN" in syslog. Any other pointers?

Comment: Here is a somewhat similar issue (with same network adapter r8169): https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=117717 and here too http://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-1766962.html . Do you dual boot into Windows? Seems then the card is left in problematic state...

Comment: @alci Thanks for the link. Yes, I dual boot with Windows 8.1
I recently updated Windows from 8 to 8.1, does it have any affect on it? Also, how can I check the state of the card?

Comment: @theharshest do not be too sure. Guild Wars plays nice on Windows but Ubuntu ended up in SYN attacks (it thinks it is dossing itself ;-) )  Only after I tweaked my router that stopped. (result was that my internet dropped out)

Comment: The **dmesg** output shows only normal startup (first 42sec). You may need this after error re-occurs, to see if anything else occurred.

Comment: @alci None of these workarounds work for me. Can you suggest anything else?

Comment: @Rinzwind oh ok, I understand that. Anything else I can do to diagnose the problem?

Comment: @david6 output remains the same even after the error occurs, can I check any other command output, or some other log? Also, if there is any workaround, please let me know. Do you think removing Windows 8 completely and keeping just Ubuntu would resolve the issue?

Comment: @theharshest did you see this topic? https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=146261
If you're using DHCP try static IP and try setting IPv6 to 'link local'

Comment: Check your wireless card and related drivers.

Comment: @theharshest Could u show a screen output of htop/system monitor (or equivalent) at the time when this occurs? As well do netstat commands (possibly `netstat -a`,`netstat -s`). http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/03/netstat-command-examples/  has some other ones you may want to look at. You may want to keep monitoring this. I just am not sure where the buffer overflow is coming from possibly a program which causes netmanager to die, or too much data from connection. If you want to monitor net more try programs on this site http://stackoverflow.com/questions/368002/network-usage-top-htop-on-linux

Comment: @theharshest what version of the kernel are you booting? This is a known problem with Realtek and at least 2.6.32, 3.2.0,  & 3.2.46

Comment: @ElderGeek `uname -r` gives `3.13.0-24-generic`

Comment: @LeartS I'm afraid if I can use static IP because I'm using wifi (comcast) and 4 other people are sharing with me.

Comment: @NoTime I would update you as soon as I get the issue again.

Comment: @theharshest There are fewer things that can cause this when connected by wire than by wireless. I would re-attempt via a tested ethernet cable. This rules out any possible RF interference being the cause of wireless issues. You say you are sharing the connection with 4 others. Is it possible one of them is capable of programming a router? You may be sharing with someone who has prioritized traffic on the port they are connected to and is a heavy user of torrents and the like. If they are saturating your connection that may be causing problems. Is your system a laptop or desktop?

Comment: @ElderGeek I can test via ethernet cable for the time being, but due to some reason I can't use that forever, I have to use wireless anyhow. No one is programming a router or prioritizing traffic or using torrent, I have confirmed. Also, I'm the only one who is facing this issue, as others are using Windows. I'm suspecting this is a buffer flow issue or something, but I can't get the right logs to track the issue. I'm using laptop.

Comment: I'm suspecting a hardware or driver issue. You could try another brand of wireless card or wireless USB adaptor (perhaps Intel or Artheros),

Comment: @theharshest Answered your question (I hope)

Comment: @ElderGeek thank you, I would accept it only after confirming. Meanwhile I have upvoted as it could be the issue.

Comment: @theharshest Did this work for you?

Comment: @ElderGeek I didn't face the issue for a long time. I'm on Ubuntu 14.04 and regularly updating it. I would update the thread the if I see the issue again, without that little I can comment.

Comment: @theharshest I'm glad you are no longer having difficulties!

Answer (score 2):

I think the driver you are using is buggy

Check Additional Drivers and install best available driver. If this solves the problem excellent. probably you've done this already? I see your wireless chip is being reported as RTL8168evl/8111evl. I don't believe this is correct as Realtek doesn't appear to make that model. Identify the wireless chip either by checking with the manufacturer of your laptop or by visual inspection.

Download the correct linux driver from http://www.realtek.com/downloads/downloadsView.aspx?Langid=1&PNid=13&PFid=21&Level=4&Conn=3

compile and install in accordance with the manufacturers instructions.

Answer (score 0):

This could also fix the problem.

This is a very very VERY Annoying bug! Which needs sorting out...

Open terminator and enter the following lines:

```
sudo modprobe ath5k nohwcrypt
sudo sh -c "echo 'options ath5k nohwcrypt' >/etc/modprobe.d/custom-wireless.conf"
sudo apt-get remove libnss-mdns
```